# How do I run a command on each file within a directory that matches a pattern?

Tags: command-line, find, grep, pipe

I'm trying to run a command on every file within a directory (recursively) that matches a pattern. I need the filename of each item that matches for the command however. This is how far I've got:

```
find . -name '*.jar'
```

That gives me all the files I'm interested in. Now, I need to run the following command on all those files:

```
jarsigner -keystore ***** -storepass ****** $FILENAMEHERE
```

How do I reference the individual items in the output of find, for the command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `jarsigner` takes only one file name at a time, use either

```
find . -iname '*.jar' | xargs -l jarsigner -keystore ***** -storepass ******
```

or

```
find . -iname '*.jar' -exec jarsigner -keystore ***** -storepass ***** {} \;
```

Comment: Yes, xargs makes things more readable! However the man says the '-l' option is deprecated: '-L 1' should do the same.